# Exposing an enum via WCF Rest. Only one attribute shown

Tags: c#, wcf

Im trying to expose an enum via my WCF REST webservice. Only one attribute gets shown. See below for the details. Can anyone advice on why this is happening?

**Class**

```
  [DataContract]
    public enum OrderAttributes
    {
        [EnumMember]
        AppointmentRef,
        [EnumMember]
        AddressRef,
        [EnumMember]
        ContactEmail,
        [EnumMember]
        ContactFirstName
   }
```

**Interface**

```
[WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "OrderAttributes")]
        [OperationContract(Name = "OrderAttributes")]
        DataLayer.OrderAttributes OrderAttributes();
```

**Service**

```
  [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Administrators")]
DataLayer.OrderAttributes IService.OrderAttributes() {
  return new OrderAttributes();
}
```

**Result of get**

```
<OrderAttributesResponse>
<OrderAttributesResult>AppointmentRef</OrderAttributesResult>
</OrderAttributesResponse>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is doing exactly what you are telling it to do, it is returning a *single* value of the OrderAttributes type. The first enum is the default enum value in this case. If you need a **list** of OrderAttributes, you have to manually build and return that list. The code in [this blog post](http://devlicio.us/blogs/joe_niland/archive/2006/10/10/Generic-Enum-to-List_3C00_T_3E00_-converter.aspx) shows how to create that list.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to label enums up as a `DataContract`. The code generator is smart enough to generate an enum in your proxy code with corresponding values.

Because you are specifying that it is a `DataContract`, it actually creates a `class` called `OrderAttributes` instead of your enum.

Comment: Removing the datacontract attribute gives the same result